# Is there a way I can use a rake task or method that can rewrite an HTML partial using erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry for the confusing title, but I will elaborate here.

ok so on the users index page of my site I have a list of Top Trending songs. The list is ordered by user rankings and this list changes dynamically as each songs aggregate ranking changes relative to each other.

```
class SongratingsController < ApplicationController
 @Top100 = Rails.cache.read('Top100')
 lastSpot = @Top100.last

 def reCalcTop100
   @Top100 =    Song.where('num_stars > ?', 0 ).order('num_stars desc,  total_score desc').limit(100)
   Rails.cache.fetch('Top100'){@Top100}
 end

 def addRatingToSong
    userID = params[:uid].to_i
    songId = params[:sid].to_i 
    rVal = params[:valR].to_i
    @averageS = []
    songRate = Songrating.find_by(:user_id => userID, :song_id => songId)
    if songRate != nil
        oldScore = songRate.rating
        songRate.update_attributes(:rating => rVal)
        @song = Song.find(songId)
        score = @song.total_score - oldScore
        newScore = score + rVal 
        averageScore = newScore/@song.songratings_count
        @song.update_attributes(:total_score => newScore,:num_stars => averageScore)
        @averageS[0] = averageScore
        @averageS[1] = @song.songratings_count
    else
        Songrating.create!(:user_id => userID, :song_id => songId,:rating => rVal)
        @song = Song.find(songId)
        newScore = @song.total_score + rVal
        averageScore = newScore/@song.songratings_count
        @song.update_attributes(:total_score => newScore,:num_stars => averageScore)
        @averageS[0] = averageScore
        @averageS[1] = @song.songratings_count
    end

    if newScore > lastSpot.total_score && averageScore > lastSpot.num_stars
        reCalcTop100
    end

     if request.xhr?

     render :json => {
                       :starData =>  @averageS

                   }
     end


end
```

end

As you can see in these two photos below I have a view partial that shows this list, but right now I have the list generated each time a user logs into the main page. But since this list is not unique to the user, I feel I am wasting time regenerating this list.

[image]

[image]

ideally I would like to generate and write a static HTML partial only when the top100 list changes, but I don't really know how to accomplish this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yep just use erb

```
vars = OpenStruct.new({some_var: some_val})
rendered_html = ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/templates/embed_code.html.erb")).result(vars.instance_eval { binding })
```

This will put the rendered html in the rendered_html variable from there you can write it to a file or do anything you want. This should work in the context of a ruby class or rake task afaik.

The vars are passed to the template and can be used as <%= some_var %> in the template.

---

Now that i've answered you actual question, i think the better solution is to just use Rails.cache to cache the rendered data.

Anything that takes a long time can be cached with

```
result = Rails.cache.fetch "some_cache_key" do
  # things you want to cache
end
```

this will cache the block and return it to result. if unstale cached data exisits in the future it will just return it from cache, if cache is empty or stale it will re-execute the block and return it into result.

---

Finally in the context fo a controller you can just use action caching which is a bit more hands off.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html for more details.

Comment: So I can cache the HTML file or just the data, because I already cache the Top100 query results, and I use a helper method that returns an instance variable of the top 10 objects from the 100 list in the cache. [cache initializer](https://github.com/MKwenhua/myOtherCv/blob/master/config/initializers/queryDB.rb) ,  [helper method getTop100 line48](https://github.com/MKwenhua/myOtherCv/blob/master/app/helpers/users_helper.rb) , [this is the erb view partial](https://github.com/MKwenhua/myOtherCv/blob/master/app/views/users/_topmusiclabel.html.erb)